# Web API POST/PUT so slow with ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

Why my web api POST/PUT getting so slow response time with following code?
The json content that POST is just <= 1024 bytes.

Method 1 and Method 2 i also tried but same result, slow...

Already try disable proxy; also slow.

```
        // GET API
        var testAsID = Convert.ToInt32(result);  
        var getQueryString = string.Format("CoID={0}&ArID={1}", testCoID, testAsID);  
        var response = await GetWebApiResponse(WebApiMethod.GET, controller, "GetByID", getQueryString);  
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //  POST
    var newAS = new ASMtnModel()
                {
                    CoID = "LKC3",
                    AsID = 0,
                    ClassID = "AR",
                    AsCode = "AS Test 1",
                    AsNameS = "AS Test 1",
                    AsName1 = "AS Name 1",
                    AsCurr = "RM",
                    AsCat1 = "ZZZZZZ",
                    AsProject = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
                    AsCrTerm = "CASH",
                    AsGLAcID = "",
                    AsGLCcID = "",
                    AsGLScID = "",
                    AsCrLmt = 0,
                    AsCrBal = 0,
                    AsTaxType = "N",
                    AsAccStatus = "1",
                    AsStatus = "A",
                    AsDateOpen = DateTime.Now,
                    AsDateLSal = DateTime.Now,
                    AsDateLPm = DateTime.Now,
                    ApvDate = DateTime.Now,
                    LastUpdateUser = "LLK",
                    LastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now,
                    AsGstDefaultValue = "E"
                };
        var httpResponseMessage = await GetWebApiResponse(WebApiMethod.POST, controller, "Create", "", newAS);  
        var result = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 


        public async Task GetWebApiResponse(WebApiMethod webApiMethod, string controller, string action, string queryString = "", object requestBody = null)
        {
          var request = "/api/" + controller;
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
          {
            request += "/" + action;
          }
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString))
          {
            request += "?" + queryString;
          }

          var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
          if (webApiMethod == WebApiMethod.GET)
          {
            httpResponseMessage = await _client.GetAsync(request);
          }
          else if (webApiMethod == WebApiMethod.POST)
          {
            string postBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody);
            // Method 1
            //httpResponseMessage = await _client.PostAsync(request, new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            // Method 2
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
              wc.Proxy = null;
              var hostUrl = _client.BaseAddress.AbsoluteUri;
              if (hostUrl.EndsWith("/"))
              {
                hostUrl = hostUrl.Substring(0, hostUrl.Length - 1);
              }
              var fullApiUrl = hostUrl + request;
              byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody);
              wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
              var resp = await wc.UploadDataTaskAsync(new Uri(fullApiUrl), bytes);

              httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
              httpResponseMessage.Content = new StringContent(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resp));
            }
          }
        }
```

**Fiddler**
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      1,604      (headers:506; body:1,098)
Bytes Received:  121        (headers:120; body:1)

*ACTUAL PERFORMANCE*
ClientConnected:    10:07:42.186
ClientBeginRequest: 10:11:33.569
GotRequestHeaders:  10:11:33.569
ClientDoneRequest:  10:11:33.569
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    10:07:59.041
FiddlerBeginRequest:    10:11:33.569 
ServerGotRequest:   10:11:33.569
ServerBeginResponse:    10:12:21.874
GotResponseHeaders: 10:12:21.874
ServerDoneResponse: 10:12:21.875
ClientBeginResponse:    10:12:21.874
ClientDoneResponse: 10:12:21.875

```
Overall Elapsed:    0:00:48.306
```

*RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)*
       ~headers~: 120
application/json: 1

**Server Request Log:**

```
Executed action EB.WebApi.Controllers.ASMtnController.GetAll (EB.WebApi) in 282.741ms

Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/api/ASMtn/Create application/json 1098
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter[1]
Request successfully matched the route with name '' and template 'api/ASMtn/Create'.
Request finished in 47928.9705ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Any one have idea on how to troubleshooting this? Anything else that i can take a look?

Comment: Did you solve this problem ? I have the same problem, most of the controllers responses 4 seconds later. I don't know what causing i've tried everything.